# Heroku Application Error but already building successfully

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Heroku logs is here, I cannot see any error from this log:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 6.x...
       Downloading and installing node 6.11.2...
       Using default npm version: 3.10.10
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 19.1M
-----> Launching...
       Released v49
       xxxx deployed to Heroku
```

Everything seems good, but I got application error when open my app. What's wrong with my app?

Following is package:

```
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "xxx.git"
    },
```

And this is server file to set port and listen to port, I set the port as 3000:

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public/assignment'));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try warping the static path into the `path` module

```
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(`${__dirname}/public/assignment`)));
```